# XML Parsing Error - Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate

I am trying to run my first Hibernate Program.
I can't figure out the problem, because the matching end-tag is actually there? 
Thanks for your help in advance!

```
Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(11) The element type "session-factory" must be terminated by the matching end-tag
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" /> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"/>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/westbahn</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" />root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" />secretpassword</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" />org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>




        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" </property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: There is no root hibernate-configuration element in your XML. There is no opening session-factory element either. Show the whole file. From the first line to the last one.

Comment: Your 'property' tags are empty: `<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" /> ... </property>`. Remove the `/` from the first tag: `<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" >`

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working, what a embrassing error this has been..

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate configuration file should look like this

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
    <property name="connection.user">xxx</property>
    <property name="connection.password">xxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>   
    <mapping resource="xxxx.hbm.xml"/>
     </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This could help you out!!

Answer (score 0):

Your 5 first property elements are wrong: you use self-closing elements although they have a body. For example:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" /> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
```

should be

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
                                  no slash here --^
```